# On using customize-cra to override antd less variable creates multiple duplicate css files on build

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, antd

I am using customize-cra to override antd less variable but it creates multiple duplicate CSS files on build.

As mentioned in antd docs https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Advanced-Guides

if I use default import of CSS like this

> @import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

it produces only **1.5MB**(Including my custom CSS) of CSS files after the build.

Then I remove @import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

And i used customize-cra , like this code.

```
const { override, fixBabelImports, addLessLoader } = require('customize-cra');
const overrideVariables = require('./src/styles/overrideVariables');

module.exports = override(
 fixBabelImports('import', {
   libraryName: 'antd',
   libraryDirectory: 'es',
   style: true,
 }),
 addLessLoader({
   javascriptEnabled: true,
   modifyVars: overrideVariables,
 }),
);
```

This produces **6MB**(Including my custom CSS) for CSS files after the build.

Am I am using it wrong or any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco). There is [craco-antd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/craco-antd) plugin that works great and does exactly what you need.

**craco.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: require('craco-antd'),
      options: {
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          noIeCompat: true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

And then you can add your variables in **antd.customize.less**

```
@primary-color: #1da57a;
@link-color: #1da57a;
```